# What's the "easier way" that deprecates the need for Data.Conduit.Util's zip?

Tags: haskell, zip, conduit

Getting started with `conduit`, and I noticed that in [Data.Conduit.Util](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/conduit/latest/doc/html/Data-Conduit-Util.html):

> Utility functions from older versions of conduit. These should be considered deprecated, as there are now easier ways to handle their use cases. This module is provided solely for backwards compatibility.

Of particular concern to me is `zip :: Monad m => Source m a -> Source m b -> Source m (a, b)`. This seems pretty useful to me - I could independently work on a way of producing `a`s and a way of producing `b`s, then just `zip` them together when I need them, rather than have to mix concerns earlier in the process.

But, like I said, I'm new in the ways of conduit, so I'm ignorant.  What are these "easier ways to handle their use cases"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's actually a mistake in the docs. The functions now provided by the util module are not deprecated, that comment applied to previous versions. I'll release a new version with corrected docs.